# Can we have different table names on source and target when using DMS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I have a source that has a table `A` and on the target, I have already created a table `B`.

Table `B` on the target is partitioned, *but the column structure and other details are the same.*

When I tried I got the error,

> table does not exist on target while using DMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't have different table names on source and target in AWS DMS.

AWS DMS doesn't give us the option to choose or enter the table details on target. It will search the same table as defined on the source and if that doesn't exist it will throw an error stating the table doesn't exist.